# initialisation of static object when linking against a static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, ld

What are the rules for initialisation of static object declared in another shared library? For instance, consider the following:

file X.hpp:

```
struct X {
   X ();
   static X const s_x;
};

struct Y {
   Y (X const &) {}
};
```

file X.cpp:

```
#include "X.hpp"
#include <iostream>

X::X ()
{
   std::cout << "side effect";
}

X const X::s_x;
```

I compiled X.cpp in a static library `libX.a`, and I tried to link the following executable against it (file main.cpp):

```
#include "X.hpp"

int main ()
{
     (void)X::s_x;  // (1)
     X x = s_x;     // (2)
     Y y = s_x;     // (3)
 }
```

with only (1) or (2), nothing happens. But if I add (3), the static object is initialised (i.e. "side effect" is printed). (I use gcc 4.6.1).

Is there any way to predict what will happen here?

I don't understand how the instruction (2) does not force the `X::s_x` object to be default-constructed, whereas (3) does.

EDIT: build commands:

```
g++ -c X.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
ar rcs libX.a X.o
g++ -o test main.o -L. -lX
```

Comment: Interesting question. Which compilers have you tried this with?

Comment: I was able to duplicate with VS 2008. Note, if you make X non-empty, it seems to work as expected. The question is why?

Comment: Have you disabled all the optimizations? I know, it shouldn't optimize out valid side effects, but still... maybe worth trying.

Comment: @julkiewicz I compiled with -O0, but this is the default on gcc. Maybe it doesn't disable everything, I don't know (I will look in the documentation).

Comment: Your describing an awful lot in English (which is bad because it is so inexact). It would be much better to put down the exact commands you use to do each action. This makes it much more exact.

Comment: @Tux-D I disagree.. I'm here to learn, among other thinks, how to express things properly in english. I tried to describe it with simple and accurate words and I don't think there is too much of english in my question. Please, point me the inexact parts and I will try to correct them (I can add the commands if you think it's important).

Comment: @Nicolas Grebille: English is a tupid language to express the problem in because we have an exact language to do it in. `g++ <XXX>-o <YYY>`. Its fine to have English in there to describe the problem. But you **MUST** describe the problem using the correct language otherwise you loose information. English is not an exact language that is why we do not use it as a development language and why you do not type English into the shell. You **MISSED** the most important part (which is why you do not have any good answers). How did you build it. **We NEED the command line used to build it**.

Comment: You should post the minimal compilable example the reproduces the error. This is the code. The command line to build. Note: If the command line invokes any build system we just want the relevant compiler/linker commands from the build file that are used to generate the error.

Comment: @Tux-D Please look at the edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default on many platforms, if your program doesn't reference any symbols from a given object file in a static library, the whole object file (including static initializers) will be dropped.  So the linker is ignoring X.o in libX.a because it looks like it is unused.

There are a few solutions here:

1. Don't depend on the side-effects of static initializers.  This is the most portable/simple solution.
2. Introduce some fake dependency on each file by referencing a dummy symbol in a way the compiler will not see through (like storing the address into a externally-visible global).
3. Use some platform-specific trick to retain the objects in question.  For example, on Linux you can use `-Wl,-whole-archive a.o b.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My program uses `X::s_x`; is this not a "symbol" in X.o? (it is of course listed by `nm -C` in X.o).

Comment: It is; however, a trivial use of X::s_x (in the sense that you aren't actually writing to it or using the value in a way that affects the output of your program) can be treated as if you did not reference it at all. If it is extremely obvious the variable is not used, it will be optimized out even at -O0  (like your cases 1 and 2).

Comment: So the standard does not specify anything about what happens when you link against an archive? In this case, I find very surprising that the program have not the same behavior when I compile the two files together and when I build a library with `X.cpp` and then link against it.

Comment: The C++ standard knows nothing about archives.  There is some language that allows arbitrarily delaying the initialization of static variables until something in the same translation unit (i.e. source file) is used.  And of course, "never" is before the first use if no function or variable is ever used.  Strictly speaking, I think the transformation in cases (1) and (2) of your testcase violates the standard... but it's sort of an edge case.